# jQuery autocomplete in edit mode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I have got a jQuery autocomplete widget in one of my page. I am using the code as follows

```
$('#city_name').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    appendTo:'#citysearchCon',
    source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#site').val()+'/ajax/city_search/'+Math.random(),
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term : request.term,
            country : $("#search_country").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            response(data);
        }
    });
},
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var link=ui.item.city_id;
        $scope.city_id=link;
    },
    open: function() {
    $("#citysearchCon > ul").css('z-index', "99999");
}

});
```

Working fine. I am using php

My question is I need to open this same page in edit mode. Then I need to show the value from db to the autocomplete select box, I just tried the following

```
<input type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" class="text-small" placeholder="City Name, State , Country" value=<?php echo $valueFromServer; ?> />
```

But its not working.

Anyone please help me

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes ? `value="<?php echo $valueFromServer; ?>"`

Comment: Also tried from angularjs ng-init method